# CSS media query not overriding styles

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I'm a bit confused. I design my page mobile first so if you open it on DevTools and see it on a mobile you'll see the design implemented on a device perfectly. On the media queries on the file of grid.css I added the style rules for the desktop view but when opening it on desktop view it doesn't apply the media queries. Here is a link if you want to check it out `https://repl.it/@GianinaSkarlett/API-Capstone` otherwise here's the snippet:

This is the CSS styles (mobile first):

```
* {
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
 padding: 0;
}


.results {
 padding: 10px;
}

.header {
 border: solid 1px gainsboro;
 padding: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 65px;
}

h1 {
 font-size: 3em;
 text-align: center;
 margin: 0;
}
h2 {
 text-align: center;
 color: white;
}

.search-background-image {
  background: linear-gradient( 
  to bottom, 
  rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5),
  rgba(0, 0, 3, 0)
  ) fixed ,url("https://image.ibb.co/nBhnQA/pexels-photo-1051075- 
  2.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  height: 211px;
  background-size: cover; 
 }

.search-type, .search-address {
 background-color: white;
 border-radius: 7px;
 border: white solid;
 position: absolute;
 height: 26px;
 top:  160px;
 padding-left: 3px;
 font-size: 9px;
}

.search-address {
  width: 110px;
  left: 190px;
 }

.search-type {
 left: 15px;
 width: 151px;
}

.button {
 background-color: white;
 border-radius: 15px;
 border: white solid;
 position: absolute;
 width: 150px;
 height: 32px;
 left: 90px;
 top: 210px;
}

.landing-page, .about-page {
  width: 100%;
 }

.landing-img {
 width: 100%;
 border-radius: 10px;
}

.text {
 display: inline-block;
 text-align: center;
 margin: 0;
 font-size: 14px;
}

.section-title {
 margin: 0;
 font-size: 18px;
 }

.clear {
 clear: both;
}
```

This is my desktop media query:

```
/* Desktops and laptops ----------- */
@media only screen  and (min-width : 1152px)  {
/* Styles */
 .landing-img {
  width: 448.22px;
  height: 635px;
  border-radius: 10px;
 }

.search-type, .search-address {
 background-color: white;
 border-radius: 7px;
 border: white solid;
 position: absolute;
 height: 40px;
 top: 376px;
 padding-left: 10px;
}

.landing-page, .about-page {
 width: 100%;
}

.section-container {
  margin: auto;
 }

 .landing-img {
   width: 448.22px;
   height: 330.68px;
   border-radius: 10px;
  }

  .text {
    width: 50%;
    padding: 20px 0 0 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 26px;
    }

   .section-title {
    width: 50%;
    padding: 0 0 10px 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 38px;
    text-align: left;
    }

    .right {
     float: right;
     }

    .left {
     float: left;
      }

     .clear {
      clear: both;
      }

  .search-type {
   left: 150px;
   width: 440px;
  }

  .search-address {
   width: 380px;
   left: 650px;
   }

  .button {
   background-color: white;
   border-radius: 15px;
   border: white solid;
   position: absolute;
   width: 110px;
   height: 40px;
   left: 1100px;
   top: 376px;
  }

    }
```

Comment: I do see your media query being applied, but your default class for `.landing-img` is overriding the width to 100%. Not sure what your question is?

Comment: Your media queries are **correctly** being applied. However, many of the selectors in your media queries are being overridden by other (generic) selectors with higher specificity (due to you loading `styling.css` after `.grid.css`). What is your **specific** problem that you're facing? As it stands, your question is too broad.

Comment: @ObsidianAge on mobile view is working as expected but on desktop view, it's not rendering with the styles given for desktop view.  I just changed the order I had placed styling.css and grid.css and it did help some rendering issues but the form, the form elements and the height of my landing-img are still rendering with the mobile view style rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it work by deleting existing media queries and creating 2 media queries, one for devices with a max width of 800px and one for devices with a min width of 801px.

Answer (score 1):

If you want `grid.css` to overwrite your responsive style, put the link to `grid.css` after the link to `styling.css` in the head of your html file.

Comment: It does solve some rendering issues but the form is still not rendering how it is supposed to on desktop view.

Comment: try to put styles for small devices inside another media query and leave only the very general styles outside

Comment: I'm going to separate them in different style sheets and see if that way I can see what's causing the problem.